# What does electromagnetic wave literally look like?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, visualization

What does electromagnetic wave literally look like? Some people on the Internet called electromagnetic wave as something that has literally only two dimensions, I think it is because of this over-publicized picture http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/emwav.html. Is it true? Personally, I don't think electromagnetic wave is two-dimensional despite most pictures depicted it as a two-dimensional wave. What do you think?

Comment: Can you provide a link to any of these claims?

Comment: I can no longer find the link because if memory serves me right that was a year ago, but you can see this link http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/emwav.html . It shows em wave as something that is two dimensional. Does EM wave really looks like that?

Comment: Now this appears to be a dupe of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169769/25301, among others

Comment: I clicked the link but the answer whether em wave is two dimensional or not can't be found in the link. So the conclusion is an individual electromagnetic wave (if there's such thing as individual em wave) doesn't look like what this link shows https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mohamed_Saleh50/publication/313725653/figure/fig7/AS:461973319098376@1487154430609/Fig-3-1-Electromagnetic-wave-propagation.png, right?

Comment: Also this question (with figures): https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/402251/em-plane-wave-the-changing-electric-field-is-in-all-directions-right/

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with such statements. Electromagnetic waves are four-dimensional phenomena. They also have quite a few degrees of freedom. The k-vector has three dimensions, there are two polarisation and two independent phases.

Comment: I see. I think some people called EM wave as something two dimensional because of this over-publicized picture of EM wave http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/emwav.html So, in reality EM wave doesn't even look like that?

Comment: That picture clearly is three dimensional. It shows a linearly polarised infinite plane wave, for which E and B always point in the same direction, but the wave pervades all of space. Obviously, a wave can only be plane in a finite volume of space-time.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but can you show me which part is three dimensional? What I'm seeing is just two dimensional plane. Why E and B always point in the same direction? Is it impossible for E and B pointing to multi different directions?

Comment: There are 3 mutually orthogonal axes in the figure.

Comment: The arrows show the direction and intensity of the electric field on the axis indicated by the line. It is easy to misinterpret the figure.

Comment: So, the conclusion is Em wave doesn't really actually look like what the picture depicted it?

Comment: The conclusion is simply this: any depiction of 3-dimensional objects on a 2-D surface is not an "exact" depiction of them. The 2-D image is an attempt to show (using our sense of perspective) what the 3-D object looks like. In the same way, a photo of a car is not the same as the car. With the real car you can walk around it and look at all sides; with a photo you cannot do that.

Comment: @ dhondt What is shown is the evolution of $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ on a line x, y constant. On another position they may have different amplitude and direction, although the plot strongly suggests a plane wave.